# Prove an inequality over the reals, given a constraint

Tags: equation-solving, number-theory

Given $a,b,c \geq 0$ and $$a + b + c = 3$$

prove

$$\frac{a}{b^2 + 1} + \frac{b}{c^2 + 1} + \frac{c}{a^2 + 1} \geq \frac{3}{2}$$

One can prove the above using a great deal of "human" insight and equation manipulation, as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O7W1ACX3TRM).

I would like to prove this with as much automatic symbol manipulation as possible.  I've tried obvious techniques using `Solve`, `RootIntervals`, and such, including the naive directly testing logically:

```
Assuming[a + b + c == 3,
 a/(b^2 + 1) + b/(c^2 + 1) + c/(a^2 + 1) >= 3/2]
```

all without success.

I have a sense there must be some way of automatically finding a solution domain for the second equation (given the constraint of the first equation), but have not been able to find it.

Comment: Could use `Minimize`: `In[296]:= Minimize[{a/(b^2 + 1) + b/(c^2 + 1) + c/(a^2 + 1) - 3/2, 
  a + b + c == 3, a >= 0, b >= 0, c >= 0}, {a, b, c}]

Out[296]= {0, {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1}}`

Comment: Whoops. I missed a response that was substantially the same.

Comment: Accepting the intent of this question is use of Mathematica in-built functions to automate and with respect, this is a [direct application](https://ubpdqnmathematica.wordpress.com/2021/09/18/inequality/) of the (weighted) harmonic mean-arithmetic mean inequality. This was alluded to by Artes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done as follows.

```
Resolve[ForAll[{a, b, c}, {a, b, c} >= 0, 
Implies[a + b + c == 3, a/(b^2 + 1) + b/(c^2 + 1) + c/(a^2 + 1) >= 3/2]], Reals]
```

> `True`

or/and

```
FindInstance[ a + b + c == 3 && {a, b, c} >= 0 && 
a/(b^2 + 1) + b/(c^2 + 1) + c/(a^2 + 1) < 3/2, {a, b, c}, Reals]
```

> `{}`

Comment: Thanks so much.  ($\checkmark$). I'm learning these functions and this is very helpful.

Answer (score 9):

```
Minimize[{a/(b^2 + 1) + b/(c^2 + 1) + c/(a^2 + 1), {a, b, c} > 0, 
  a + b + c == 3}, {a, b, c}]
```

> `{3/2, {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1}}`

Comment: `NMinimize[{a/(b^2 + 1) + b/(c^2 + 1) + c/(d^2 + 1) + d/(a^2 + 1), 
  a + b + c + d == 4}, {a, b, c, d}]`

Comment: This results in `{2., {a -> 1., b -> 1., c -> 1., d -> 1.}}`, not proving the inequality.

Answer (score 4):

The **most straightforward** method involves `Simplify` with assumptions being its second argument:

```
Simplify[ a/(b^2 + 1) + b/(c^2 + 1) + c/(a^2 + 1) >= 3/2, 
          a + b + c == 3 && a >= 0 && b >= 0 && c >= 0]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

The assumption that `a, b, c` are nonnegative is important (this should be mentioned in the original question), e.g.

```
With[ {a = 2, b = 2, c = -1}, 
       a/(1 + b^2) + c/(1 + a^2) + b/(1 + c^2) >= 3/2]
```

> ```
>  False
> ```

For another examples how `Simplify` (or `FullSimplify`) can be powerful see e.g.

[Solving a system of diophantine equations from a mathematical competition](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161940/solving-a-system-of-diophantine-equations-from-a-mathematical-competition/161942#161942)

or

[Am I missing anything? Solving Equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26147/am-i-missing-anything-solving-equations/26148#26148).

**EDIT**

Taking a look at the inequality with three variables $a, b, c \geq 0$ **we can generalize** it to the case with four variables $a, b, c, d \geq 0$ such that $a+b+c+d=4$:
$$\frac{a}{b^2+1}+\frac{b}{c^2+1}+\frac{c}{d^2+1}+\frac{d}{a^2+1}\geq2$$

We take $2$ for the r.h.s. of the inequality since it  is natural to expect that the minimum is achived when all numbers are equal i.e. $a=b=c=d=1$, and now this works well

```
Simplify[ a/(b^2 + 1) + b/(c^2 + 1) + c/(d^2 + 1) + d/(a^2 + 1) >= 2, 
           a + b + c + d == 4 && a >= 0 && b >= 0 && c >= 0 && d >= 0]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

it takes a few minutes, while `Minimize` (analogously like in another post) haven't provided the result for much longer time. On the other hand the construction involving `Resolve`, `ForAll`, `Implies` works similarily like `Simplify`.

Comment: Thanks ($+1$).  The original problem didn't specify that $\{ a,b,c \} >0$ but your example shows that it is indeed necessary, so I've updated the question.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork You are welcome. I updated my answer with a generalization of the inequality to the four variables case, which is computationally much more expensive than three variables case.

Comment: `FindInstance[
  a/(b^2 + 1) + b/(c^2 + 1) + c/(d^2 + 1) + d/(a^2 + 1) < 2 && 
   a + b + c + d == 4 && a >= 0 && b >= 0 && c >= 0 && d >= 0, {a, b, 
   c, d}, Reals] // AbsoluteTiming` results in `{248.005, {}}` on my comp.

Comment: The comment regarding `FindInstance` doesn't make sense (as usual from this user).  `FindInstance`  doesn't serve anything and  the inequality should be `a/(b^2 + 1) + b/(c^2 + 1) + c/(d^2 + 1) + d/(a^2 + 1) >= 2`.

Comment: @artes: The question is how to show that `x+y+z==3&&{x,y,z}>=0` implies the inequality `a/(1 + b^2) + c/(1 + a^2) + b/(1 + c^2) >= 3/2`. The negation of this implication is `a/(b^2 + 1) + b/(c^2 + 1) + c/(a^2 + 1)  < 3/2 &&     a + b + c  == 3 && a >= 0 && b >= 0 && c >= 0` (see [Negation of implication](http://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi3/sec_propositional.html)). The `FindInstance` command shows that this negation is false, so the implication is true.  The same for the generalization for four variables. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.